# I have problem in show item of database with v-for in vue.js

Tags: php, html, vue.js

I have problem in show item of database with v-for.
I get data from database and show it in console log but  isn't show in app.vue .

app.vue

```
    <template>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row well">
          <div id='app'><input type='button' @click='allRecords()' value='Select All newss'>
            <div class="col-sm-3 alert-success p" v-for="news in newss" :key="news">
              <p>{{ news.news_num }}</p>
              <p>{{ news.news_title }}</p>
              <p>{{ news.news_description }}</p>
              <p>{{ news.news_year }}/{{ news.news_month }}/{{ news.news_day }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newss: [],
      newsid: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    allRecords: function() {
      axios.get('/api.php')
        .then(function(response) {
          app.newss = response.data;
          console.log(app.newss);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you please include the output for `console.log(app.newss);`?

Comment: Probably not the issue but `v-for="news in newss" :key="news"` should likely be `v-for="(news , i) in newss" :key="i"`

Comment: 1. 0: {news_id: "2", news_num: "2", news_title: "H", news_description: "2 H", news_imgurl: "2.jpg", …}
2. 1: {news_id: "14", news_num: "15", news_title: "B", news_description: "3 B", news_imgurl: "15.jpg", …}
3. length: 2
4. __proto__: Array(0)

Comment: can you post the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(app.newss));`?

Comment: Wait, what is `app` exactly? can you try `this.newss = response.data;`?

Comment: i haven't problem in get data ,only can not show it in site

Comment: how can I show item of newss ?

Comment: please help me .I don't know what am I doing?

Comment: Did you try using ‘this.newss = response.data’?

Comment: yes,but not difrent